# Android EditText specify next destination when clicked on keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 9 `EditText`, 3 on top then under them another 3 and then also another 3.
I want when the user click on the Next button on the Keyboard to move to the `EditText` on its right and not the one below it. Right now if you click Next it will go to the one underneath it till you reach the bottom one where it becomes "Done".

Is there anyway to make the next button on the Keyboard take us to a specific `EditText`?

I read few articles here before posting they suggested `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/` but that didn't work. I think its for another usage.

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/dreampark" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/merrygoround" />



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/horseride"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:onClick="Play" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="107dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nbr1"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nbr2"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nbr1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nbr1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nbr3"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nbr2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nbr2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nbr4"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nbr3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nbr3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:background="@drawable/frstg"
            android:onClick="PlayFirstGame"
            android:layout_above="@+id/partTwoNbr4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/noplay"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/partTwoNbr1"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nbr1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/partTwoNbr2"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/partTwoNbr1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/partTwoNbr1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/partTwoNbr1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/partTwoNbr3"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/partTwoNbr2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/partTwoNbr2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/partTwoNbr2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/partTwoNbr4"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nbr4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nbr3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nbr3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/partTwoNbr5"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/partTwoNbr1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/partTwoNbr6"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/partTwoNbr5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/partTwoNbr5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/partTwoNbr5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:background="@drawable/scndg"
            android:onClick="PlaySecondGame"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/partTwoNbr6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:src="@drawable/noplay"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried  android:imeOptions="actionNext"

Comment: I already have the Next button on my keyboard, the problem is that its taking me to the wrong "next" EditText.

Comment: Mention android:imeOptions="actionNext"  For Every Edit Text And Add  android:imeOptions="actionDone" For Final or Last Edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these line to your EditText

```
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textAllCaps="false"
 android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

& for last EditText with Done Action

```
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: It didn't work, it still took me to the one below it instead of the one next to it.

Comment: @JamesAnd post your xml here

Comment: hey its work at  my end after adding above lines to each of EditText at bottom.

Comment: Which theme you applying to app or activity?

Comment: Yes It's Working @Suhas B

Answer (score 0):

why not do it programatically, according to android docs keyboard will pop up when there is focus on edit text, hence when you get the input for the first edit text do. `secondEditText.performClick()`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, input fields will be smartly assigned focus according to the layout.

However, you can set a [`OnEditorActionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) on the `TextView` and handle the [`IME_ACTION_NEXT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_NEXT) action id, where you shift the focus to desired input field.